# Permission error in GCP when creating a new compute instance but service account does have permissions

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, cloudbuild.yaml

I am running a `cloudbuild.yaml` job in Google Cloud Platform that builds, pushes and tags a Docker Image and then it creates a Compute Engine instance to run that image via `gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud.create-with-container`. I also specify a service account to be used in this step:

```yaml
- id: "Create Compute Engine instance"
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: [
    'compute',
    'instances',
    'create-with-container',
    '${INSTANCE_NAME}',
    '--container-image',
    'eu.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${PROJECT_ID}-${REPO_NAME}',
    '--zone',
    '${ZONE}',
    '--service-account',
    '${SERVICE_ACCOUNT},
    '--machine-type',
    'n2-standard-4'
    ]
```

However I am getting an error:

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create-with-container) Could not fetch resource:
 - Required 'compute.instances.create' permission for 'projects/...'
```

The service account in use does have the permissions for that as it has been assigned `"role": "roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1"`, which includes `compute.instances.*` as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles).

Anyone has experienced this or a similar situation and can give a hint on how to proceed? Am I missing something obvious? I have tried using other service accounts, including the project default compute account and get the same error. One thing to note is I do not specify a service account for Docker steps (gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you are not misinterpreting service accounts.
There is a special service account used by Cloud Build.
There is also the service account to "be used" by the VM/instance you are creating.

The "compute.instances.create" permission should be granted to the special Cloud Build account, not to the account for the instance.

The Cloud Build account has a name like 123123123@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com.

In the Cloud Console go to Cloud Build -> Settings -> Service Accounts
and check if correct permissions are granted.

[image: Cloud Console]

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly my problem. Permissions were granted but disabled.